# How to override GET method depending on JWT payload in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

First of all, I hope the title of this question is clear enough. The following lines will make things clearer if it is not the case.

I have different users in my database. Some are part of the staff and some are just regular users.
In my API, I have a /users route. My idea is that when a staff member requests it (GET), he will see only the staff users and when a regular user will request it, he will only see the regular users.

Whether or not the user which makes the request is a member of the staff or not is an information which is stored in the JWT token.
Therefore, I used the following code:

```
class CustomUserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        token = self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')[7:] # [7:] to get rid of 'Bearer '
        is_staff = jwt.decode(token, None, None)['is_staff']
        print(is_staff)
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(is_staff=is_staff)
        return queryset
```

This code works but is there a more direct / logical way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

It feels a bit off storing what is essentially a server-side permission/setting on the client side (even though some people do use JWT for that). What if a user is promoted to/demoted from staff? You'd have to revoke all such client tokens? Also, what if you need to attach more conditions to these queries?

I think a slightly more flexible approach is to store some kind of a user id in the JWT token, then use a `TokenAuthentication` [class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) with [JWT](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/json-web-token-based-authentication-in-django-b6dcfa42a332) to establish the identity of the user, attach it to something like `request.user` and then in your `get_queryset` method filter by `request.user.is_staff`. That way, you can attach any context/filters/permissions to the authenticated users on the server side and don't need to rely on the client to present explicit claim(s) to filter out the objects they can access. You'd end up with an extra call to the database to populate `request.user`, but you might end up needing that anyway.

Comment: I was thinking about giving my tokens a small expiration time to avoid the role change problem even though I agree with you this is still a problem while the token is valid. Anyway, my question was more about django rest than the security issues. To be clearer : does Django offer a mechanism to treat those cases or do you have to manually get the token, decode it and check the permission every time you want to adapt the api response to the user role ?

Comment: It's not just security issues, it's more about separation of concerns by using the proper DRF tools. You deal with the JWT token in something like your own `BaseAuthentication` subclass, where you can parse the token, or use the third-party `JWTAuthentication` from simplejwt as suggested in another answer. You filter for the right objects inside `get_queryset` based on your current business logic such as `is_staff` after you've verified the user and/or their claims in authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating with a JWT token in the header retrieves the user so your view will have access to `request.user` and all of the user's attributes in every method after the `dispatch()` method (the first method that is run after `.as_view()` is triggered when sending a request to an endpoint).

If you're using [djangorestframework-simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt), the [DRF recommended JWT package](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#json-web-token-authentication), all you need to do is this:

```
class CustomUserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            queryset = queryset.filter(is_staff=True)
        return queryset
```

Comment: qwertzuiop seems to specifically rely on storing the `is_staff` claim in the JWT token and not the user id. JWT will store whatever claim you put in it, it does not automatically store or retrieve the user.